# Android App Stuck on Splash Screen only after first open when downloaded from Google Play

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm having a very odd issue.
My app gets stuck on the Splash after the first boot only, only after it's downloaded from the Google Play Store. It doesn't do it in a development build.

Once I kill the app and reboot it all is fine from then on.

What could cause such an issue? Are there processes that run only during the first boot that might get stuck?

Comment: It is happening with me also. Any luck on solving this?

Comment: that's my problem too. how can we fix that? I use android studio and java